# Is the recovery drive (flash usb drive) from Windows 8.1 enough to restore a full windows installation, even if I install Ubuntu on my laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1

I have an Acer Aspire Switch that I would like to try to play with Linux, but I would like to have the possibility of reverting to Windows if the Linux becomes really unusable (driver problems).

I've already created the recovery disk using the builtin tool from Windows 8.1 with Bing, copying the recovery partition to the recovery drive. I've tested and have already restarted my machine and booted from this flash drive, being able to see "reset options" and such.

Fact is: after changing the whole device with Linux (different partitions and such), is this recovery flash drive enough to reset/restore my machine to factory conditions if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no, not on its own. You want to create an image of your drive. For this, you'll need an external drive at least as big as your Acer drive. On my Windows 10 machine, this option is under Control Panel > System & Security > Back up and Restore (Windows 7). The wizard is accessed from the "Create a system image" button on the left. If I recall correctly, Windows 8 is similar. Once the image is created you can reload the image painlessly from your recovery disk no matter what you did to the drive. Just connect both recovery drive and system image drive to the computer and boot into the recovery drive. Select restore from image and follow the on screen instructions.

**Having said that...** I would like to caution you against doing that. If you just want to play around with Linux and see what it has to offer, the safest option is to just use a live disk. The [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop) install disk doubles as a live disk and would probably work best on your two-in-one screen. There is nothing done to your computer when you use a live disk so it is safe. If that isn't sufficient, then you can use a virtual machine, such as [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Restoring your original setup from there is a simple matter of removing the virtual machine. If that still is not sufficient for your purposes, then you might want to dual boot Windows and Linux. In that case, restoring is just as simple as uninstalling Linux and extending your Windows partition again.

Comment: When I reset my machine, it seems it's in "factory state". Are you saying this is done by the recovery disk still using my Windows 8.1 on HDD, and not just by the recovery disk itself? Do you know if there's any official documentation stating that?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media Says "If you're running Windows 8.1 with Bing, contact your device manufacturer for info on how to get installation media for your edition of Windows.". That's why you're saying I need to create an image of my drive?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/windows-81-create-a-recovery-drive-image/ded91a27-d3aa-4ff1-98ec-4ca136d07fb3?auth=1 Here is an explanation like yours about the media.